# Unable to import base64 image into react component with webpack

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I created a b64Images.js file in my images folder. Inside it I have the following:

```
export const placeholder = "data:image/png;base64,longb64string"
```

I'm trying to import it into one of my react components using:

```
import { placeholder} from '../../../images/b64Images.js'
```

It's able to find the file, but i'm getting the error:

```
Module parse failed: fullpath/b64Images.js Line 1: Unexpected token
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
```

It's just a js file and my webpack is already configured to handle this. I don't have any issues importing my reducer functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is to forget converting the images yourself, and install this package.

https://github.com/antelle/base64-loader

```
import { placeholder} from '../../../images/b64Images.js'
```

becomes

```
import placeholder from 'base64!../../../images/image.png'
```

sadness becomes happiness